# NoSQL Alternative of sql.js

Tags: javascript, nosql

I'm currently using SQL.js to consume my local .sqlite database and using fetch() to retrieve the sqlite file locally.

I am thinking of migrating my relational database to noSQL. Is there any module I can use to also consume a physical file of a noSQL database? It should be purely local, no servers/localhost or whatsoever. This will be ran in a browser so browser restrictions should be considered.

I tried to search online but all I could find are those that still need to be hosted or ran via localhost.

Thank you!